# How to remove floats of a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

For example:

```
 [['D', 'D', '-', '1', '.', '0'],['+', '2', '.', '0', 'D', 'D'],['D', 'D', 'D']]
```

This is:

```
D D -1.0
+2.0 D D
D D D
```

I want to extract the values, put in differents variables and know the line and column where the signal was (so i can put symbol that corresponds to the old value).

```
D D x
y D D
D D D

[['D', 'D', '-1.0'],['+2.0', 'D', 'D'],['D', 'D', 'D']]
```

Comment: how did you get your lists? this looks wrong to me.

Comment: from a .txt file.
        for line in arq:
            maze.append([item for item in line.strip()])
        return maze

Comment: have you really lines without spaces?

Comment: could you show us the full code?

Comment: I removed the spaces.

Comment: and why did you remove the spaces?

Comment: It's a map for a maze, the spaces have no value in the map.

Comment: But you need them to separate the Letters from the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall). The pattern `[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+` is used to extract float values from a string.

```
import re

list2d = [['D', 'D', '-', '1', '.', '0'],['+', '2', '.', '0', 'D', 'D'],['D', 'D', 'D']]
lists = list()

for l in list2d:
    s = ''.join(l)
    matches = re.findall(r"D|[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", s)

    lists.append(matches)

print(lists)
# Output
[['D', 'D', '-1.0'], ['+2.0', 'D', 'D'], ['D', 'D', 'D']]
```

Comment: Can i float(item)? '-1.0' is a string in this case, right?

Comment: Yes, the argument mqy also be `+/-`. Refer to [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) for the detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

```
  import itertools  
  merged = list(itertools.chain(*list2d))
  print [x for x in merged if not (x.isdigit() or x in '-+.')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a list of list. Take directly the lines from your file and split them with the help of regular expressions:

```
maze = []
for line in arq:
    maze.append(re.findall('[-+][0-9.]+|\S', line)
```

Comment: I need the list of lists because it's a map for a maze.

Comment: And you get one, but in the correct format and not with single characters.

Comment: Thanks! I got it now, this way i create my list of lists already formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, could add more information in your description.

```
    import csv

    csv_file = open("maze.txt")
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    maze = []
    for line in csv_reader:
        for char in line:
            maze.append(char.split())

    print(maze)

    # Output

    [['D', 'D', '-1.0'], ['+2.0', 'D', 'D'], ['D', 'D', 'D']]
```

Comment: '-1.0' is a string in this case, right?
Can i float(item) ?